# If a jetliner is giving TOGA thrust but never releases the (parking) brake, will the brakes heat up?

Tags: thrust, braking

From my - admittedly - limited knowledge of physics, the energy generated from the engines needs to go somewhere; will it go into the brakes or does it just dissipate into the air?

Comment: Aren't the real questions: Why would one do so, and how long will it take to realize the mistake (if not indented)?

Comment: @U.Windl it was more a hypothetical scenario anyways. I know there are plenty of safety features that this shouldn't happen (for too long)

Comment: Also a quick "thank you" to everyone who commented here, I appreciate it :)

Comment: This question deserves a lot more upvotes, simply because of the amount of debate it sparked. Well done Nico!!!

Comment: Absolutely, and now I ask: name one form of propulsion that does anything other than to impart **force** on what it is trying to move?  Simple thought experiment.  Take a block of wood and set it on the table.  Apply force with your hand.  At  will accelerate until force = friction (and aerodynamic drag!).  The  Power of the block is Force x Velocity.  Now nail the block to the side of a merry go round. *Relative* to where you place it there is no V.  But the block + the merry go round *recieve* the force, same as the jet and earth.  Easier to see if the merry go round moves.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Brakes absorb energy through dynamic friction. If the plane doesn't move, the brakes do not absorb any energy, and do not heat up.

**The energy is going into the air either way**, whether the brakes are applied or not.

The only difference a parking brake makes is whether the reaction force, arising from Newton's third law, acts on the aircraft alone or on the aircraft+Earth system. Momentum will be imparted to that system.

The additional ballast of M⊕ is about 10<sup>19</sup> times the weight of the heaviest airplane, so it reduces its acceleration by a factor of 10<sup>19</sup>. Planets are a heavy load to move.

More technical:

The amount of momentum imparted to the air and to the aircraft is equal, but the amount of energy is not.

Energy absorbed by the brakes is equal to `E=F*S`, where F is braking force and S is distance traveled by the plane. If the brakes hold the plane, `F=T`, T being thrust, but `S=0`, and `E=T*0=0`. i.e. the plane won't move.

This assumes the brakes work perfectly and hold. Normally the brake will be released at half power. Past that, if the plane is lightly loaded, or has a lot of thrust, or if the runway is wet, the plane can start skidding, so you'll get movement and heating at the tires... And then [this is what can happen](https://www.baaa-acro.com/crash/ground-accident-airbus-a340-642x-toulouse).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

So there is no friction and with that force absorbed through the clamping force the brakes are applying to the disks?

Comment: @Nico, think of it like this, the brakes aren't absorbing any energy from the engines, they absorb only the kinetic energy of the airplane.  If ground speed is zero there is no kinetic energy to absorb.

Comment: So I`ve asked ChatGPT about this as well, and it is very adamant that the brakes would heat up due to the static friction occuring between the brake pads and the wheel...
Do you by chance have any source on this?

Comment: Therac is correct.  Rub your hands together vigorously as hard as you can and see if your hands heat up.  Then push your hands together as hard as you can and try to move your hards together.  You feel the movement in your arms but the hands don't heat up due to friction.

Comment: @wbeard52 but wouldnt the muscles heat up in this case? causing the body to sweat after a certain amount of time?

Comment: @Nico I've done power assurance runs on CRJs where you run the engines up to TO thrust with the parking brake on. The brake temp indications are unaffected. It's as if the tires were just rigidly attached rubber feet like on the legs of a chair. There has to be movement between pads and discs.

Comment: Is the tire-to-ground friction sufficient to keep the airplane stopped with the engines at full power?  If the tires are skidding across the ground, the brakes will heat up a little via conduction from the heated tires.

Comment: I agree the muscles would heat up but that isn't due to friction.  The heat is due to the chemical release from the muscles pushing the hands together.... or something like that.

Comment: Never ask ChatGPT anything technical if you expect a correct answer.

Comment: @OrganicMarble or indeed anything at all.

Comment: of course depending on how good the brakes are the brakes may end up slipping, causing serious heating. You're assuming perfect braking action here, no slipping brakes, no skidding tyres, and no mechanical stresses on the brake mechanism.

Comment: @Mark Not always. For GA, sometimes enough, some not. For an airliner, on the very edge, hopefully-just-enough. Easily becomes "not enough" in cold or wet weather. For a jet fighter, not even close.

Comment: @OrganicMarble It's possible to use ChatGPT as a calculator, but only if you already know the answer. Just two days ago, it claimed the energy content of JP-1 was 0.43 MJ/kg and that it meant a turbine would need 3.5 kilograms of fuel to produce 100 kWh. Where did any of these figures come from? No one knows, it's buried deep in the weights of the language model.

Comment: @Therac it knows no math, science, or engineering. Just how to string words together in a plausible way. Very high powered BS generator, just what the world needs.

Comment: @Therac lol that's funny because according to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation_fuel): "*Kerosene type BP Jet A-1, **43.15 MJ/kg***" so it's off by 2 decimal points (assuming JP-1 and JET-A1 have similar calorafic value). Also, it's calculation is hot garbage; it would require around 8.4 kg to produce 100 kwh (840 kg if we use the calorafic value GPT came up with).

Comment: @AdityaSharma Yep. It's not just wrong; it's not even internally consistent, and in ways that make no sense. Maybe ChatGPT 5 with full Wolfram Alpha integration will be able to do good math. As of right now, it can be massaged to give the right answer, but you need to know the answer to massage it.

Answer (score 1):

To be precise the engines do not generate energy, they convert chemical energy into kinetic energy, which can be measured as heat and thrust.

As long as the wheels of the aircraft are not rotating, no energy is transferred by/via the brakes, as there is no movement between brake pads and brake rotors that would cause friction create heat.

In any case, over time all of the energy  released by this process dissipates into the atmosphere, and eventually into space.

Comment: "Heat dissipates into the atmosphere".  Good.  Where does the thrust go?

Comment: Let it go Robert.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni [Here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145805/discussion-between-sophit-and-aditya-sharma) is an entire discussion we had on that. Summary: with the brakes engaged and engines running, the earth and the air particles are gaining kinetic energy (both in opposite directions) - that's where the mechanical energy "produced" by the engine goes. Due to friction between earth and air, this kinetic energy will eventually be converted into heat.

Comment: @AdityaSharma thanks.  I won't worry about the friction of air slowing the planet's rotation.  Indeed, lucky for those at the equator, earth has a boundary layer!  But correctly, we realize fuel moves air, *reaction* (of varying efficiencies) provides propulsion force.  Locking brakes means plane + earth become a much more massive object.  To summarize, no friction heat will created unless the wheels rotate or skid.  Otherwise, it goes to earth.  Boring bookkeeping, but that is the science.  Our TOGA plane makes the world a bit warmer, and adds (or subtracts) from its rotation.

Comment: "it goes to earth" 

Comment: @Jpe61 I mean, yes it does; as Bianfable said, "*But a jet engine would, because it accelerates air backwards, so something else must be accelerated forwards (conservation of momentum).*" so if the plane cannot accelerate, whatever it is anchored to (the earth) will have to. (not sure if your comment was meant to be sarcastic...)

Comment: @AdityaSharma Not all of it! The engine accelerates air, and the reaction force of accelerating the air accelerates the earth. It is not correct to say the energy goes to earth. Especially since most of the energy the jet "creates" is heat!

Comment: @Jpe61 yes, about 70% of fuel's chemical energy is converted into heat, while the remaining 30% is converted into mechanical energy. Of the 30%, some is acquired by air and the remaining by the earth (in the form of kinetic energy).